# Local img not importing through Array in JS React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image

I've been trying to build a basic portfolio as a practice project throughout the day. I have a set of sample sites I want to show. However the issue I am having is that when I try to import a photo through a web link (see id: 1) it imports, but when I try to import an img from my local img folder it isn't loading. I tried importing the img using two other methods as well as shown through id:2 and id:3.

The only that seems to work is id:1 but the images I want to use are locally stored.

My data array: data.js

```
    export const products = [
    import theBestTestImg from "./src/assets/img/bestTest.png
      {
        id: 1,
        img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3585047/pexels-photo-3585047.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
        link: "http://aTestSite.xyz",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        img: "./assets/img/anotherTestImg.jpg",
        link: "https://anotherTestSite.com",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        img: {theBestTestImg},
        link: "https://theBestTestSite.ca",
      },
];
```

Portfolio List: ProductList.jsx

```
import "./productList.css";
import Product from "../product/Product";
import { products } from "../../data";

const ProductList = () => {
  return (
    <div className="productList">
      <div className="productListTexts">
        <h1 className="productListTitle">Motivate & inspire</h1>
        <p className="productListDesc">
          This is a creative portfolio that your work has been waiting for.
          Beautiful homes, stunning portfolio styles & a whole lot more awaits
          inside.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="productListList">
        {products.map((item) => (
          <Product key={item.id} img={item.img} link={item.link} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductList;
```

Product.jsx

```
import "./product.css";

const Product = ({ img, link }) => {
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="productBrowser">
        <div className="productCircle"></div>
        <div className="productCircle"></div>
        <div className="productCircle"></div>
      </div>
      <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        <img src={img} alt="" className="productImg" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Thank you for any input and help on this. I'm still learning JS and react and really am unsure why my local images don't import as seen in attached image, yet my web link does.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to require() local images in React, due to [how webpack bundles your app](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images).

```
<img src={require(img)} alt="" className="productImg" /> // this assumes every "img" object is a path to a local image
```

You can also just require() the images in the image object to keep your components as they are:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3585047/pexels-photo-3585047.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
  link: "https://example.com",
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  img: require('./assets/img/anotherTestImg.jpg'),
  link: 'https://example.com',
 },
]

// ...
<img src={img} alt="" className="productImg" />
```

Comment: I'm just going through the docs you linked, and not fully understanding how I can go about using a local img though like in id:2 or id:3

Should I go with something like:

    <code>
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: require("./assets/img/testImg.png"),
    link: "http://testsite.xyz",
  },
    </code>

While keeping Product.jsx the same?

Comment: yeah as long as you require() local images, it doesn't matter where you do it - see my updated answer. If the image is local, you have to require('./localpath.png')

Comment: Clearly there is something else wrong since I've done the following and am still getting nothing to load:

data.js

  {
    id: 1,
    img: require("./assets/img/testImg.png"),
    link: "http://testSite.xyz",
  },

ProductList.jsx

        {products.map((item) => (
          <Product key={item.id} img={item.img} link={item.link} />
        ))}

Product.jsx

      <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        <img src={img} alt="" className="productImg" />
      </a>

Only way I can get the image to work if I link it from a site, but the local ones still don't

Comment: Are you sure your local image path is correct? "./assets/..." assumes the assets folder is in the same directory as the products data object.

Comment: Yea - data.js  is in my src folder. I had to double and triple check that myself to make sure the error wasn't that easy fix

Comment: That does sound strange, as long as webpack is configured properly it should handle local images. Can you post a minimal codesandbox with the same folder structure you have?

Comment: Hope that helps

https://codesandbox.io/embed/distracted-wildflower-td442?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your sandbox wasn't loading so I removed some stuff and added a default tsconfig, but otherwise, it's working fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-volhard-51vc9?file=/src/data.js. Check to see if your tsconfig looks similar.

Comment: Clearly something is up with my files. I need to go through it all. I'm going to flag it as solved though since I was able to recreate what you did in sandbox as well. Thanks so much for the help on this.

Comment: Unfortunate that we couldn't figure this out. I had similar issues where something pretty basic wasn't working as it should have before, and ended up scrapping and rebuilding from a fresh react project. A very messy solution but saved me a few times. Hopefully your project isn't too big where this last-resort isn't possible. Good luck and let me know if you do figure it out.